# Python code for 'Verifiable Canonical Generation of the Generator g', FIPS 186-4, returns False

Tags: python, cryptography

I have already asked this question on [Crypto StackExchage](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/96485/python-code-for-verifiable-canonical-generation-of-the-generator-g-fips-186-4) and one person already replied. I have incorporated the changes, suggested in the answer, but it still returns false.

More context: I am going through the [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) and on the page 43, there is a algorithm, **A.2.3  Verifiable Canonical Generation of the Generator g**, to generate generators. I wrote a Python code, see below, that encodes this algorithm. However, it always returns false against the test data which I took from [NIST Test Vectors](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/Digital-Signatures#dsa2vs) (Test Vectors, FIPS-186-4, DSA. I have also posted the whole file at [gist](https://gist.github.com/mukeshtiwari/de84b80b835cf761b7ae4ac021124604#file-pqggen-txt-L4965-L4969)).

[image]

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256


P = 0xff600483db6abfc5b45eab78594b3533d550d9f1bf2a992a7a8daa6dc34f8045ad4e6e0c429d334eeeaaefd7e23d4810be00e4cc1492cba325ba81ff2d5a5b305a8d17eb3bf4a06a349d392e00d329744a5179380344e82a18c47933438f891e22aeef812d69c8f75e326cb70ea000c3f776dfdbd604638c2ef717fc26d02e17
Q = 0xe21e04f911d1ed7991008ecaab3bf775984309c3
domain_parameter_seed = b'180180ee2f0ae4a7b3a1ab1b8414228913ef2911'
ggen = b'6767656e'
index = b'79'
G = 0xc52a4a0ff3b7e61fdf1867ce84138369a6154f4afa92966e3c827e25cfa6cf508b90e5de419e1337e07a2e9e2a3cd5dea704d175f8ebf6af397d69e110b96afb17c7a03259329e4829b0d03bbc7896b15b4ade53e130858cc34d96269aa89041f409136c7242a38895c9d5bccad4f389af1d7a4bd1398bd072dffa896233397a



def compute_gen():
    k = (P - 1) // Q
    for count in range(1, 0xffff):
        U = domain_parameter_seed + ggen + index + count.to_bytes(2, 'big')
        W = int.from_bytes(SHA256.new(U).digest(), 'big')
        g = pow(W, k, P)
        print(g)
        if g != 1:
            break
 
    return g


print (compute_gen() == G)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`domain_parameter_seed`, `ggen` and `index` must be converted to bytes-like objects with `bytes.fromhex()`:

```py
U = bytes.fromhex((domain_parameter_seed + ggen + index).decode('utf8')) + count.to_bytes(2, 'big')
```

With this change the code works.